# Rails best practice: use before_filter or application_controller helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I'm working on a big rails project. There are a bunch of classes that use the before_filter to set the @current_user variable (there are actually a ton of these before_filter methods for other variables, but I'm using this one for an example):

```
before_filter :current_user
```

Which calls the application controller's current_user method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= session[:user_id].present? ? User.includes(:memberships).find(session[:user_id]) : nil
    end
```

The other option is to use an application_controller helper method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    helper_method :get_current_user

    def get_current_user
        @current_user ||= session[:user_id].present? ? User.includes(:memberships).find(session[:user_id]) : nil
    end
```

Then I replace all the @current_user references in the app with a call to the helper method:

```
get_current_user
```

This ensures that the method only gets called in the methods or views where it's needed, right? Is there a performance benefit to using the before_filter?

Comment: There's no need to call it `get_current_user`. In typical Ruby code the `get_` part is redundant. The only difference here is you're force-loading it, which kind of defeats the purpose of lazy-loading.

Answer (score 1):

In your case both behave in the same way and are equal in the result you get - cached instance variable `@current_user`.

[`helper_method`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method):

> Declare a controller method as a helper. For example, the following
>   makes the current_user and logged_in? controller methods available to
>   the view

[`before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action) (because `before_filter` is deprecated):

> Append a callback before actions

Because of memoization being used the result is same in both cases.

The difference is that with `before_action` you are actually calling the method each time any action is called, whereas `helper_method` just provides you with a helper. If the logic performed in both was more complicated, indeed there would be a performance difference - `before_action` would be more resource consuming.

P.S. Two things are different, its uses are different and you can't really compare them.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful. I didn't write the app, and there are a TON of these calls for a lot of different controllers (some of which ARE filtered by qualifying the before_filter with 'except' or 'only'). So it just seams DRYer to me to use the helper method, that gets called when needed, rather than adding the before_action method, which may or may not be needed. Is there a way to keep the @current_user instance variable but tie it to an application_controller method so that it's only instantiated when it's needed?

Comment: @yeldarb sure, just move your `helper_method` to `application_controller.rb` and it will be available in all controllers